# не получается исправить ошибку в коде на питоне, прошу о помощи

Tags: python

помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде, он выдает ошибку выполнения.
Условие задачи: Василию очень нравится клеточный автомат «Game of life», поэтому он решил попробовать придумать что-то подобное. Для простоты, Василий решил определить свой клеточный автомат на массиве из n
ячеек, каждый элемент которого может быть в живом или неживом состоянии.

Эволюция массива в клеточном автомате Василия происходит итеративно следующим образом:

Если у неживого элемента есть ровно 1
живой сосед в текущем состоянии массива, то на следующей итерации он станет живым. Соседями для элемента на позиции i
являются элементы на позициях i−1
и i+1
, если соседа на такой позиции не существует, то считается, что он мертв.
Василий — гуманист, поэтому все живые элементы в его автомате остаются живыми.
Смотрите секцию примечание для примеров эволюции.

Вам дано некоторое начальное состояние всех элементов, и вам нужно помочь Василию определить, каким будет состояние массива через m
итераций эволюции.

Входные данные
Во входных данных находятся несколько наборов входных данных. В первой строке находится одно целое число t
(1≤t≤103
) — количество наборов входных данных. Далее следуют наборы входных данных.

Первая строка набора входных данных содержит два целых числа n
и m
(2≤n≤103,1≤m≤109
) — количество ячеек в массиве и количество итераций.

Вторая строка набора входных данных содержит строку длины n
из «0» и «1» — описание начального состояния. «1» обозначает живую клетку, а «0» — неживую.

Гарантируется, что сумма значений n
по всем наборам входных данных не превосходит 104
.

Выходные данные
Для каждого набора входных данных выведите строку из n
символов «0» и «1» — состояние массива через m
итераций эволюции.

```
Пример
входные данные
4
11 3
01000000001
10 2
0110100101
5 2
10101
3 100
000
выходные данные
11111001111
1110111101
10101
000
```

написала по этой задаче код, но он выдает ошибку в процессе выполнения(в 18 строке AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'). Помогите пожалуйста исправить!!!
мой код:

```
n=int(input())
a=["1"]
b=["0"]
for i in range(n):
    kol, it=map(int, input().split(" "))
    st=input()
    st=st+"0"
    st=list(st)
    q=[]
    for j in range(len(st)):
        if j!=0:
            if st[0]=="0":
                if (st[j-1]=="1" and st[j+1]=="0") or (st[j-1]=="0" and ast[j+1]=="1"):
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        elif j==0:
            if st[j]=="0":
                if st[j+1]=="1":
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        elif j==len(st)-1:
            if st[j]=="0":
                if st[j-1]=="1":
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        st=q
        q=""
```

Очень прошу помочь!!!

Comment: Вы не используете значение `it` - количество итераций. Исправьте код так чтобы оно было как-то задействовано.

Answer (score 1):

Для количества шагов `m=10^9` невозможно сделать m преобразований массива за отведенное время. Это говорит о том, что требуется полностью изменить подход.

Если посмотреть, что будет с серией из `L` нулей в начале или в конце, ограниченная единицей: единицы будут продвигаться на одну позицию каждый шаг. Таким образом, если `m>=L`, то нулей не останется, иначе останется `L-m` нулей.

Серия из `L` нулей в середине массива, ограниченная двумя единицами, будет сжиматься на каждом шаге на две позиции, так что, если `2*m<L`, то останется `L-2*m` нулей, иначе останется `L&2` нулей (т.е. при нечетной длине один ноль будет неубиваемым)

Сложность этого решения `O(n)`, т.е. пропорциональна длине входных данных, которая совсем невелика (1000)

Answer (score 0):

По-первых, вы в некоторых местах использовали оператор сравнения вместо присваивания.

Во-вторых, надо делать два списка: текущее состояние, и следующее.

В алгоритме не разбирался, может брать, в нем тоже ошибки есть.

Comment: присваивание исправила, но не представляю, как исправить оставшиеся недачеты

Comment: В ответе предполагается пошаговая симуляция, что для миллиарда шагов не уложится в лимит. Надо думать как сразу угадать финальную конфигурацию. Для этого нужно порисовать решения руками или ещё раз внимательно поглядеть на примеры и ответы.

Comment: Но как это воплотить в код...

Comment: @Настя А вы уже разобрались, что будет с нулевыми промежутками разной длины и теми, что на краю?

Comment: нет, еще не до конца

Answer (score 0):

Приведённая в вопросе ошибка возникает из-за того, что в начале вы присваиваете `q` список

```py
q=[]
```

а в конце цикла - строку

```py
q=""
```

Соответственно, на второй и последующих итерациях цикла значение `q` - это уже не список, а строка, у которой нет метода `append`.

Comment: вы правы, но теперь проблема, что выводится неверный ответ...

Comment: Если этот ответ решает приведённую в вопросе ошибку, примите его (серая галка слева).